# PHP dom content clone and print on same page

Tags: php, clone

I have gone through multiple *Stack Overflow* questions but failed to get the desired response. I have also tried using JavaScript clone method and PHP using AJAX but no luck.

I have an page which loading content from external JS. Upon DOM content load I would like to again print the page with PHP and the content should be seen in page source.

Page code looks like this:

```js
<body> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.js"></script> 
<div id="loadhere">Data from Javascript Load Here</div> 
</body>
```

As the data comes from JavaScript it stays on user view frontend but when we do pagesource only above code shows.

Comment: Page code looks like this -

<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.js"></script>
<div id="loadhere">Data from Javascript Load Here</div>
</body>

As the data comes from Javascript it stays on user view frontend but when we do pagesource only above code shows.

Comment: Show your code, please. Comments don't count.

Comment: First Method Used -

`<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 <script src="somejavascript.js" async></script>
 <div class="class-pulling-results-from-top-js"></div>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('load', function(){
      $(document).ready(function(){
       $("resultDiv").clone().appendTo("body");
       console.log(x);
   });
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>`

With above the problem is the code is getting cloned on pagelevel but nothing shows up in view pagesource

Comment: 2nd Method -
`<body>
 <script src="somejavascript.js" async></script>
 <div class="class-pulling-results-from-top-js"></div>
<div id="PrintResult"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).on('load', function(){
$(document).ready(function(){
$("resultDiv").clone().appendTo("body");
   });
  });
function dispData(x){
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "OtherFile.php",
  data:{y:JSON.stringify(x)},
  async:false,
  success:function(res){
$('#PrintResult').html(res);
}
});
}
 </script>
</body>
</html>`

With this result is <object Object>